# Sum of Fibonacci number

Tags: number-theory

Let $F_n$ denote the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number, given by $F_1=F_2=1$ and $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$. Then for fixed $p$ show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom {n}k F_p^k F_{p-1}^{n-k}F_k = F_{p n}$$

Is there a way that we can solve this using recursion. I know that the Fibonacci number sequence depends on recursion to operate. I tried to use the generating function of the Fibonacci, without any success. Any help? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Fibonacci numbers are well-known to have an exponential growth, and for a fixed couple of constants $\alpha,\beta$, by letting $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\overline{\varphi}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, we have
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\alpha^k \beta^{n-k} F_k = \frac{(\alpha\varphi+\beta)^n-(\alpha\overline{\varphi}+\beta)^n}{\sqrt{5}}\tag{1}$$
due to the binomial theorem. It is reasonable to expect that the solution to the given problem is not very far from being a consequence of a similar identity. Indeed
$$ F_{pn}=\frac{\varphi^{pn}-\overline{\varphi}^{pn}}{\sqrt{5}}=F_p\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\varphi^{pk}\overline{\varphi}^{p(n-1-k)} \tag{2}$$
simply follows from $(a^n-b^n)=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+a b^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$.
Are you able to turn the RHS of $(2)$ into the LHS of the original identity, by exploiting $\varphi\overline{\varphi}=-1$, $\varphi+\overline{\varphi}=1$, $F_m = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\varphi^m-\overline{\varphi}^m\right)$ and the binomial theorem?

Comment: Jack, we posted our answers pretty much at the same time and although they are a bit different they are similar. If you think my answer is redundant, let me know and I'll erase it.

Comment: @Hamed: I was going to write you the same. Our approaches are indeed very similar, just presented in a slightly different way. I guess it is no big deal to keep both answers, I am going to turn mine into CW.

Comment: it would be helpful the end, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use $F_n=(\phi^n-\psi^n)/(\phi-\psi)$, where $\phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ and $\psi=(1-\sqrt{5})/2$, to show that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} F_p^k F_{p-1}^{n-k} F_k&=
\frac{(\phi F_p+F_{p-1})^n-(\psi F_p+F_{p-1})^n}{\phi-\psi}
\end{aligned}
$$
(replace the formula for $F_k$ in the sum). Then use the formula again (having in mind $\phi\psi=-1$) to conclude $\phi F_p+F_{p-1}=\phi^p$ and $\psi F_p+F_{p-1}=\psi^p$.